# Why could split-brain situation happen in Resourcemanager HA using ZooKeeper

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, apache-zookeeper, high-availability, resourcemanager

I was wondering why we need the extra *ACL fencer* to avoid *split-brain situation* in Resourcemanager HA using ZooKeeper. Because I thought when active RM thinks that it is still active with temporarily disconnection, it would be notified that its session has expired after re-establishing with the zookeeper clustesr. At this point, there would be only one ActiveStandbyElectorLock znode, created by standby RM. So there would never be *split-brain situation*.

As what could be seen from below: [Zookeeper Programmer's Guide](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.13/zookeeperProgrammers.html)

> Session expiration is managed by the **ZooKeeper cluster itself**, not
> by the client.
> When the ZK client establishes a session with the cluster it provides
> a "timeout" value detailed above. This value is used by the cluster to
> determine when the client's session expires. Expirations happens when
> the cluster does not hear from the client within the specified session
> timeout period (i.e. no heartbeat). **At session expiration the
> cluster will delete any/all ephemeral nodes owned by that session**
> and immediately notify any/all connected clients of the change (anyone
> watching those znodes). At this point the client of the expired
> session is still disconnected from the cluster, it will not be
> notified of the session expiration until/unless it is able to
> re-establish a connection to the cluster. The client will stay in
> disconnected state until the TCP connection is re-established with the
> cluster, at which point **the watcher of the expired session will
> receive the "session expired" notification.**